# wrong number of template arguments (3, should be 4)

Tags: c++, templates, properties, arguments, getter-setter

I tried to use property on c++ to use it instead of too many setter and getter function in data class have lots of member variable.

there are two property class. first one has fixed setter and getter function by default set, get. second one support using custom setter and getter function of its class. below is the code

```
template <class T>
class Property
{
    T data;
public:
    // access with function call syntax
    Property() : data() { }
    T operator()() const
    {
        return data;
    }
    T operator()( T const & value)
    {
        data = value;
        return data;
    }
    // access with get()/set() syntax
    T get() const
    {
        return data;
    }
    T set( T const & value )
    {
        data = value;
        return data;
    }

    // access with '=' sign
    operator T() const
    {
        return data;
    }
    T operator = ( T const & value )
    {
        data = value;
        return data;
    }

    typedef T value_type; // might be useful for template deductions
};



// a read-write property which invokes user-defined functions
template <class T, class Object, T(Object::*real_getter)(), T(Object::*real_setter)(T const &) >
class RWProperty
{
    Object * my_object;
public:
    // this function must be called by the containing class, normally in a
    // constructor, to initialize the RWProperty so it knows where its
    // real implementation code can be found
    void operator () ( Object * obj )
    {
        my_object = obj;
    }

    // function call syntax
    T operator()() const
    {
        return (my_object->*real_getter)();
    }
    T operator()( T const & value )
    {
        return (my_object->*real_setter)( value );
    }

    // get/set syntax
    T get() const
    {
        return (my_object->*real_getter)();
    }
    T set( T const & value )
    {
        return (my_object->*real_setter)( value );
    }

    // access with '=' sign
    operator T() const
    {
        return (my_object->*real_getter)();
    }
    T operator = ( T const & value )
    {
        return (my_object->*real_setter)( value );
    }

    typedef T value_type; // might be useful for template deductions
};
```

and i'm testing these properties in OptionSet class before putting it into project code

```
#include <QString>

class OptionSet
{
public:
    explicit OptionSet() {}

    Property<QString> m_MeshMode;

    RWProperty<uint, OptionSet, &getNumberOfVbo, &setNumberOfVbo> uNumberOfVbo; 
    // this causes problems

protected:

private:
    Property<uint> m_uNumberOfVbo;

    uint setNumberOfVbo(const uint& rVboCount)
    {
        // something to do here
        return m_uNumberOfVbo(rVboCount);
    }
    uint getNumberOfVbo() const
    {
        return m_uNumberOfVbo();
    }

};
```

but in use RWProperty, even i passed 4 arguments of template like member type, class type has setter and getter function, getter function pointer, setter function pointer in order, it says

> "wrong number of template arguments (3, should be 4) :
>   RWProperty <uint, OptionSet, &getNumberOfVbo, &setNumberOfVbo> 
>   uNumberOfVbo"
>
> "provided for 'template<class T, class Object,
>   T(Object::*real_getter)(), T(Object::*real_setter)(const T&)> class
>   RWProperty : class RWProperty"

I guess i'm doing something wrong to pass arguments in template.

is there anyone knows what happened?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the actual, complete and unedited error log?

Comment: 1. To get the address of a member function you need to include the class name `&OptionSet::getNumberOfVbo`, 2. `OptionSet` is incomplete at the point you want to get the addresses of member functions

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: i'm so sorry i edited it

Comment: @PiotrS.: thank you for your comment! but if i include the class name in template argument &OptionSet::getNumberOfVbo, &OptionSet::setNumberOfVbo, it says "incomplete type 'OptionSet' used in nested name specifier" for included code

Comment: @zzangzzangmen I told you it's incomplete, move the declaration of `uNumberOfVbo` after the member functions are declared

Comment: @PiotrS.: you have sharp eye! right, i knew class member function need to include its qualified-id to use it function pointer in external. but it said same error so i felt i'm too sleepy. As a result, i realized that i used undeclared function to pointer before it was declared. i overlooked declaration order to call it even the functions is in the class. thanks!
i hope nobody have same mistakes for spending a few hours like me

Comment: but after i changed the code for declaration, it still said "could not convert template argument '&OptionSet::getNumberOfVbo' to 'unsigned int (OptionSet::*)()' "
this problem was from setting getNumberOfVbo to 'const' so i removed 'const' keyword, it works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three mistakes in your code:

Firstly, to get the address of a member function, you need to include the class name:

```
RWProperty<uint, OptionSet
         , &OptionSet::getNumberOfVbo
//         ~~~~~~~~~~~^
         , &OptionSet::setNumberOfVbo> uNumberOfVbo;
//         ~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

Secondly, to form a pointer to `const` qualified member function, you need to append `const` keyword to the declaration of that pointer:

```
T (Object::*real_getter)() const
//                         ~~~~^ to match 'uint getNumberOfVbo() const'
```

Lastly, `OptionSet` inside `OptionSet` itself is an *incomplete* type. You can't refer to its member unless the point of declaration of that member comes first. This basically means you need to reorder your declarations within `OptionSet` so that `setNumberOfVbo` and `getNumberOfVbo` comes *before* you declare `uNumberOfVbo` data member:

```
class OptionSet
{
    //...

    uint setNumberOfVbo(const uint& rVboCount) { /*...*/ }
    uint getNumberOfVbo() const { /*...*/ }
    // Ok, now they are known and can be found in the class scope

    //...

    RWProperty<uint, OptionSet
            , &OptionSet::getNumberOfVbo
            , &OptionSet::setNumberOfVbo> uNumberOfVbo;
};
```

Comment: And hopefully uint isn't a typedef for unsigned int. But that's outside the scope of the question and the above still holds.